# Create and update a virtual column value in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My table structure is

```
customer  column1 column2(int) 
  1        sale      2            
  1        return    1            
  1        sale      3             
  1        sale      1             
  1        return    1
```

**Question:-**

> create a virtual column(column3) which has start value `column3 = 0` and update its value according to `column1` and `column2` values. I could not find a query which create and update a virtual column together.

e.g. `IF(column1='sale',column3 + column2, column3-column2 )`

```
// start value of column3 = 0 for each product
customer  column1 column2(int) column3
  1        sale      2             2  //0+2 because it is a sale 
  1        return    1             1  //2-1 because it is a return 
  1        sale      3             4  //1+3 because it is a sale 
  1        sale      1             6  //4+2 because it is a sale 
  1        return     1            4  //6-2 because it is a return
```

Comment: How do we know which way to arrange them? (return = last sale+2last sale - current) , why not sale = return + sale or something? where is the logic

Comment: @sagi  First row will always will be of a sale and return will be always after sale. e.g. sale 2 shirts and customer returns 1 shirt then the customer has 1 more shirt left... its a rental service... hope it clears your question..

Comment: I think you messed up your modelisation. If you need to create column like that dynamically... it seams bad. Take your time, think about what you really need, check the basics of modelisation and try something better.

Comment: Kind of, but i guess you have more then just 1 product.. shirts and pants and ETC.. so how can we know which is what

Comment: @sagi Wait i am editing my question. Thanks for reminding that too...

Comment: If you need help for modelisation, maybe you can ask on :
[stackexchange](]http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design). But you'll need to be clear on your needs ;)

Comment: @ThinkTank Thanks for the link but i am in the last stage of project and need that fast don't have enough time to redesign database... :)

Comment: You need to go fast, ok. But I'm not sure using a solution which cant work 'll be faster than to think about something correct and easy to use.

Comment: @ThinkTank What do you suggest for this special condition... Should i change my whole database structure for this particular problem? is it right way of doing this ??

Comment: You have no way of uniquely idenitfying these rows. As such, you have no 'database structure' in a strict RDBMS sense of the word, and this problem is unsolvable.

Comment: @Strawberry is this not possible in php ?? can you provide some php code to achieve that ? and if possible give solution for single product only..

Comment: It's not possible to return the data in a consistenly reliable way with the present schema.

Comment: @Strawberry Edited my question check now...

Comment: No significant/material difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys i am looking for some alternatives :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CROSS JOIN should solve this:

```
SELECT
    t.column1,
    t.column2,
    CASE
WHEN t.column1 = 'sale' THEN
    @id :=@id + t.column2
ELSE
    @id :=@id - t.column2
END AS column3
FROM
(SELECT @id:=0) var
CROSS JOIN table1 t
```

Comment: Working fine thanks..but can this is possible for different products... e.g.:- different calculation for product a and b ??

Comment: You can extend number of variables based on number of product types and tune `CASE` part, but if they are too much it's better to do it via external script (PHP) by running the query for each product.

Comment: Can you provide me example if i have more then 1 product.... Any help would be appreciated.... :) e.g. count products from table and create variable and calculate column3 based on that... :)

Comment: First select `DISTINCT` all products from the table then make a loop with this query and `WHERE product = 'some_product'` using PHP or something similar.